# Filter- model's query set based on the match from another model's ManyToMany fields

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have this problem, where I want to list Projects that the Applicant is *only* **capable of**; I have models as this>>

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_title= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('ProjectCategory')

class Applicant(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('ProjectCategory')

class ProjectCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

The Applicants have categories field to specify what he/she is capable of; let's say one chooses "python" and "Django.
Also two projects are created where>>

**1st Project**: (project_title: Need a Django Developer)[on categories field: requires "python" & 'Django']

**2nd Project**: project_title:Need Developer [on categories field: requires "python" & 'Django' & 'Django-Rest']

How can I make Queryset where I can display only **1st Project** which the applicant is only capable of or interested in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming we would be storing the `categories` the user has chosen in `Applicant` model,

```
# Getting the categories for the applicant
categories_for_applicant = Applicant.objects.filter(user=user_obj
                                ).first().categories.values_list(
                                                 "category", flat=True)

# Getting the list of projects based on categories for applicant
projects_list = Project.objects.filter(
                    categories__category__in=categories_for_applicant)

 
# To filter dynamically for a list of categories, assuming below for example
categories = ["python", "django"]
# Since django uses lazy query, this doesn't make a DB call
project_objects = Project.objects.all()
for category in  categories:
    # This will give all projects containing lets say "python"
    # Now we have objects with python as categories
    # In second iteration we will filter again on those with "django". Now we have projects with both python and django
    project_objects = project_objects.filter(categories__name=category)

 # Final project objects will contain projects objects with both python and django and so on.
```

Comment: thanks!! This gets most of it. This gets query set with **any matches** but what if I want to filter project_list with **And matches** i.e like _Project.object.filter(categories_category_in=['category1' & 'category2' and 'category3']_ .How to get a query set matching all three categories?

Comment: No, the first approach -`Project.objects.filter(
            project_categories__in=categories_for_applicant)` was what I was looking for. Also it's Dynamic instead of hard-coded like in the second approach. The only problem with the first approach was it returned a query set that matched any element from categories_for applicant. I want it to return a query set that matched all the elements from categories_for applicant.

Comment: @R.jan There is no direct way to do this in django. Please check if the updated answer helps